# Custom IconItemRender Lag using with list

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, builder

I have custom IconItemRender used in List. When i embed image to list and test on device the animation of list scrolling is not cool it`s lagging. If not embed image the animation of list scrolling is ok.

Any suggestion why list lagging?

Here is code for:

```
package components
{
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.Font;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

import mx.core.DPIClassification;

import spark.components.IconItemRenderer;
import spark.components.Image;
import spark.components.LabelItemRenderer;
import spark.components.supportClasses.StyleableTextField;

public class Shops extends IconItemRenderer
{   
    private static var bkgColor:Boolean;

    protected var storeName:StyleableTextField;
    protected var floor:StyleableTextField;
    protected var _data:Object;
    protected var floorTextSize:int;
    protected var promotions:Image;
    protected var promotionHolder:Sprite;

    [Embed(source="assets/map_list320.png")]
    public static const mapList:Class;

    public function Shops()
    {
        //TODO: implement function
        super();

        switch (applicationDPI) {

            case DPIClassification.DPI_160:

                floorTextSize = 11;
                break;

            case DPIClassification.DPI_240:

                floorTextSize = 20;
                break;

            case DPIClassification.DPI_320:

                floorTextSize = 16;
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @private
     *
     * Override this setter to respond to data changes
     */
    override public function set data(value:Object):void
    {
        _data = value;

        if (storeName) storeName.text = _data.title;
        if (floor) floor.text = 'етаж: ' + _data.floor;

        // the data has changed.  push these changes down in to the 
        // subcomponents here           
    } 

    /**
     * @private
     * 
     * Override this method to create children for your item renderer 
     */ 
    override protected function createChildren():void
    {   
        // promotion if exist
        promotionHolder = new Sprite();
        addChild(promotionHolder);

        // store name
        storeName = new StyleableTextField();
        storeName.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat( getStyle( "fontFamily" ), getStyle( "fontSize" ), getStyle('color') );
        addChild( storeName );

        // floor
        floor = new StyleableTextField();
        floor.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat(getStyle( "fontFamily" ), floorTextSize, 0x999999);
        addChild(floor);

        // map


        var img:Image = new Image();
        img.source = mapList;
        img.cacheAsBitmap = true;
        img.width = 64;
        img.height = 64;
        addChild(img);
    }

    /**
     * @private
     * 
     * Override this method to change how the item renderer 
     * sizes itself. For performance reasons, do not call 
     * super.measure() unless you need to.
     */ 
    override protected function measure():void
    {

    }

    /**
     * @private
     * 
     * Override this method to change how the background is drawn for 
     * item renderer.  For performance reasons, do not call 
     * super.drawBackground() if you do not need to.
     */
    override protected function drawBackground(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        graphics.beginFill(bkgColor ? 0xFFFFFF : 0xf0f4fb, 1);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        bkgColor = !bkgColor;
    }

    /**
     * @private
     *  
     * Override this method to change how the background is drawn for this 
     * item renderer. For performance reasons, do not call 
     * super.layoutContents() if you do not need to.
     */
    override protected function layoutContents(unscaledWidth:Number, 
                                               unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.layoutContents(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        // layout all the subcomponents here            
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {

        // position the field 
        storeName.x = unscaledWidth / 10;
        storeName.y = (unscaledHeight - (storeName.textHeight + floor.textHeight + (unscaledHeight/10))) / 2;

        floor.x = unscaledWidth / 10;
        floor.y = storeName.y + storeName.textHeight + (unscaledHeight/10);


        // we draw a separator line between each item
        var lineY:int = unscaledHeight -1;
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xd9d9d9);
        graphics.moveTo( 0, lineY );
        graphics.lineTo( unscaledWidth, lineY );

        drawBackground(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What Device?  What version of Flex?  What version of AIR?  I have had serious performance issues on iOS w/ scrolling; but works great on Android.

Comment: IOS, flex 4.6, AIR 3.4.. I think i`m doing something wrong with image embed :)

Comment: Nothing looks inherently wrong to me.  It strikes me as odd you didn't implement a measure method.  And you don't seem to be positioning your children in any way.  You may try upgrading to AIR 3.5 SDK.

Comment: Also you are not calling the super class methods in all of your overrides in the setter for data, createChildren(), and updateDisplayList(). This could be problematic. You are extending IconItemRenderer but not using the built in icon object. You can switch to LabelItemRender or remove your Image component and try using the icon property.